# I can't get data in class with irregular name in scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying make scrapy in a dynamic site, but I don't know why I cant get no data, I want the product name and value of product, but in my cod return None.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import math

url = 'https://www.paodeacucar.com/categoria/alimentos/basico-da-despensa/acucar-e-adocante?qt=12&p=1'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}


site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
qtd_itens = soup.find('span', class_='flex flex-col xs:flex-row xs:justify-between xs:items-center')#.get_text().strip()#hqqzIZ,kJrwFu'
print(qtd_itens)
```

This is the website link

```
https://mercado.carrefour.com.br/mercearia/alimentos-basicos?category-1=mercearia&category-1=3002077&category-2=acucar-e-adocante&facets=category-1%2Ccategory-2&sort=score_desc&page=0
```

Result the value in the tag. Because the tag span and div have a strange name, so I can't identify this in my code to get result different than None.

Comment: `This is the website link` There are two websites, one in the code, and one in the text of your question. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: Sorry, I send the old code with other site, but the real is the second.

Comment: The more complex way is to scrape graphql endpoints from where information is being hydrated into page (check Network tab -- XHR calls).
The less complex way is to just use Selenium and get that information.